# getting id from another xml?

Tags: android, xml

Im my android project i have 2 java class and 2 xml file. each java class only can see one of the xml file because of setcontentView)();

java1 -> xml1

java2-> xml2

i have to see the imageView1 at java2 class but the imageview is at xml1 so the class cant see it. What should i to ?

Comment: explain "see", please! On the other hand, if you want to access a view that is not available for your current activity, then your application structure is probably wrong. If you put the two activities together, you can still split the view using say `ViewFlipper`.

Comment: let mee explain more about my problem. java1 has setcontentview(tab1);   java2 has setcontentview(tab2); in java1 i am getting a text from edittext which is in tab1, and i want to post the text which i get it to a textview in tab2. But if i write findViewByid(R.id.textview) it does not work. Cant do anything with it !

Comment: is java1 here an Activity extension? and so is java2? please clear it up editing your question, it will be more readable. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling the java2 activity from java1 (or backwards), then you can use the Intent's `putExtra` method to pass any value you want from your first activity to the second.

If you need this relation to work backwards too, you should call `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`.

These two steps will solve your problem - in case that i've understand it right.

Comment: it diddnt helped me. I think i have to look at layout inflater but i am doing smt wrong over there.

Comment: what kind of problem are you facing? please share some sources, to take a look at, so we can help you more

Answer (score 0):

If this is a control in a different layout, it won't exist, so knowing the ID (even though that's easy to get) won't help you at all.